# Colorama doesn't work on custom printing function?

Tags: python, colorama

**I have a typewriter function that prints strings in the terminal character by character. I am using this typewriter function instead of "print()". Colorama 'Fore.'doesn't seem to work on my function. Any ideas?  Thanks!**

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

        def typewriter(message,s1,s2):
            for char in message:
                sys.stdout.write(char)
                sys.stdout.flush()
        
                if char !="\n":
                    time.sleep(s1)
                else:
                    time.sleep(s2)

       def firstMenu():
           typewriter(Fore.YELLOW + "Make a numeric selection:  ",0.03,0.2)
           typewriter("[1]"+ Fore.YELLOW +"Start")
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what goes wrong than "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Yes! Sorry! The 'Fore.Yellow' for example, does not make my text yellow using my typewriter function. It seems to work in the print function but I don't intend to use print in my program.